# Where can I find a lexicon of adjectives?

Tags: parts-of-speech, lexical-semantics, adjectives, lexicon

I am currently looking for a list of adjectives that I can use as a seed for a machine learning model. These do not need to be annotated. Are there any open source lexicons that exist which could be used for this purpose?

Comment: Maybe PanLex has this: https://apps.panlex.org/teradict/?lg=eng

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/)'s adjectives:

> *WordNet® is a large lexical database of English. Nouns, verbs,
>   **adjectives** and adverbs are grouped into sets of cognitive synonyms
>   (synsets), each expressing a distinct concept.*

You can find them in the archive or retrieve them programatically with tools such as [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html). More detailed explanations about the adjectives in WordNet can be found in the following paper:

1. Gross, Derek, and Katherine J. Miller. [**"Adjectives in wordnet."**](https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/ijl/3/4/10.1093_ijl_3.4.265/1/265.pdf?Expires=1494933177&Signature=QlTr2xUP0BQQElJ~FHUwC~sx3pzxFwN21A5MA-9Ix4zxK7PVPI51jDZUjEN5wyM8rdWk0zym8E74TyV68SimfHu02ltZ0EpNYq2EMct06oMjNDQwQnDOZxpiWED9VLdAqzNWpi0YnsfQQVZQAC7RNzfIa~qVxaf0k1NWMPGiy-2vv2Cu~6BFAN71zDfDYqz5gNNUtvYOwQagXZx2N8XImZmg3BkrrgS~lY7BKi1776Rn~Ib5fKHzQavhQS0sOMTHiiLjCKGM~tdYas7Utm7hWn-6P1~Ps73PUO0Y9oNM9e4zi4TWZcHLJoIh2~V2qdwFAhItH1eqzYtEtUkOBprRwg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIUCZBIA4LVPAVW3Q) International Journal of lexicography 3.4 (1990): 265-277.
   APA

Answer (score 0):

You can extract adjectives (for many different languages, not only English) from the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page). Wiktionary has a higher coverage of the vocabulary than WordNet.